# Open .string files as an NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, localization, nsdictionary

How do I open a .string file as an `NSDictionary`?

**Edit:** I want to be able to use it like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"dict.plist"];
NSDictionary *strings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"Strings.strings"];
```

Comment: Used how? What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to convert then into an objective-c object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want it in a dictionary, you can load it using `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:]`, since it is in [“Old-style ASCII”](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/OldStylePlists/OldStylePLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001012-BBCBDBJE) format. I have used this technique before on Mac OS X, but I'm not sure you can do the same for iOS.

However, if you want a translation for a particular string, there are at least two ways to do it:

1. [`NSLocalizedStringFromTable()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-SW16) will allow you to load strings from files other than the normal `Localizable.strings` file. Provide the name of your strings file (without the extension).
2. NSBundle's [`localizedStringForKey:value:table:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method. This essentially performs the same operations as the method above, and as above, provide the name of your strings file without the extension.

Answer (score 0):

.string files just store key/value pairs, like:

```
"StringKey" = "some localized text";
```

you can get the text for a specific key using `NSLocalizedString`. If you want to get all the strings in a file, I suppose you could read the `Localizable.strings` file and parse it.

Comment: Hi... can you write some code here, for getting string of a particular key.