# How can I localize text in xib views without creating xib for each language?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I want to localize text inside xib view. Currently I have several xibs for each language.

Is it possible to localize the text inside xib file without creating separate xibs for each language?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to learn about .string files.

Here is a related question you can look at for more info:
[Open .string files as an NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680814/iphone-string-files)

Comment: Can you reference the translations in a .strings file from a xib, or do you need to set label (etc) values in code if you only want one xib instead of one xib per language?

Comment: Great question @jrturton, and I'm not certain of the answer to it.  To reference .strings from within a xib itself?  I suspect it might be possible via KVC, but I've never tried.

Comment: see this tutorial:http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

Comment: I've never localised an app and to me it seems silly to have different versions of a xib just for localisations - any future changes to the xib would involve a lot of effort and risk.

Comment: Things like multiple XIB's really come into play and must be considered when you're considering localizing into languages that have dramatically different alphabets, styles and size constraints compared to a traditional Western, or "Roman" style.  E.G. Arabic (right to left) or Asian (or, as we call it in the software world, "CJKV").

Comment: Im already use .strings files. However I use them inside interface builders. I want to reference specific string from .strings file inside xib.

Comment: I want to reference specific string in xib, without writing code.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from Android background, I was asking the same question. Even Apple [recommends](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LocalizingInterfaces.html) creating separate xib files for each language. Fortunately, this process can be automated using the `ibtool` in a build script. It's described nicely in [this article](http://developer.casgrain.com/?p=94).

Answer (score 0):

> Localization are applied for text not Xib.  So, you don't need to
>   consider xib file.  Localization is easy not too Complicated.  Check
>   this link It will help You.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

This problem was driving me nuts.

I came across this post and several others while trying to make xib localization easier for myself. I posted my method of including IBOutles for labels/buttons on this question, worked great for me, keeps all changes limited to the Localization.strings files.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15485572/1449834

Answer (score 0):

I think localize xibs directly is not an good option. I'm using https://github.com/steipete/Aspects to hook the awakeFromNib method of UILabel and localize text there. Example:

```
 #define Localized(_v_) NSLocalizedString(_v_, nil)
 NSError *err = nil;
[UILabel aspect_hookSelector:@selector(awakeFromNib)
                 withOptions:AspectPositionAfter
                  usingBlock:^(id<AspectInfo> aspectInfo) {
                      UILabel *label = aspectInfo.instance;
                      NSString *lStr = Localized(label.text);
                      if (lStr) {
                          label.text = lStr;
                      }
} error:&err];
```

If you have UIButton and other UIView to handle, you could just hook awakeFromNib of UIView and localize each kind of view.